# Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.Filters.IDataSourceFilterFactory

Tags: sitecore

Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.Filters.IDataSourceFilterFactory issue after configuring CD server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit SwitchMasterToWeb.config  inside /app_config/Include folder and comment below section

```
      <!--<add key="item">
        <FiltersFactory>
          <param desc="definitionDatabaseName">web</param>
        </FiltersFactory>
      </add>-->
```